# if statement with execute command in PHP

Tags: php, linux, shell

What I want to do is to write an If statement in PHP (on my Linux server) that will work like this:

1) Ping a specific IP.

2) If the IP is not reachable, wait and ping again in 2 minutes.

3) If the IP is not reachable again, then execute a command that will shut down the server.

What I can't find is how to execute a shell command from a PHP file?

Comment: Use the system function in PHP... read http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php

Comment: You'd `exec('yourscript.sh');`. For security, it's not recommended to let php do that. http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: Thank you for your answers! My server doesn't have access on the internet, so i assume that it is secure to do it by PHP!

Comment: How do you expect to ping an IP without Internet access?

Answer (score 0):

You can `exec` this in PHP:

```
while ! ping -c 1 example.com
do
    sleep 2m
done

remotely_shutdown example.com
```

where `remotely_shutdown` is the command to shut down the server. Obviously you can't do that by connecting to the server unless it's up, so I expect you're using something like AWS EC2.